# How to parse an EPS file using C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, eps

Please help me on **parsing an EPS file** in order to extract only the required information, *using C#.*

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What kind if "required information" are you thinking of. Meta information (creator, used fonts...), text content, etc...

Answer (score -2):

Here is a library in Java that maybe could help you to read some informations in EPS files

[EPS file reader](http://www.spectotechnologies.com/en/open-projects/imageio-eps-plugin)

Comment: Really wish this was in C#... I know this is old but please be aware of this [Self Promotion FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) and disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Comment: If there was any other open source EPS reader, I would share other but there is really not much!